# Naturally sort strings which contains numerics, letters and date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, time

here is the array I want to sort:

```
let documentData=[
{'title':'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,06/14/2018,1.14.03 PM.pdf'},
{'title':'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,06/14/2018,5.14.03 AM.pdf'},
{'title':'04 Images > Image0010-image59323.jpg'},
{'title':'04 Images > Image0010-image44005.jpg'},
{'title':'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,08/04/2018,5.14.03 PM.pdf'},
{'title':'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,12/14/2018,10.14.03 AM.pdf'},
    ];
```

Here is the code I use to run the natural sort.

```
console.log(documentData.sort((a,b)=>
      a.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\>| |\-/g,'')
        .localeCompare(
            b.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\>| |\-/g,''),
            undefined,{numeric:true, sensitivity:'base'})));
```

Here is the output I get

```
[ { title: '01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,06/14/2018,1.14.03 PM.pdf' },
  { title: '01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,06/14/2018,5.14.03 AM.pdf' },
  { title: '01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,08/04/2018,5.14.03 PM.pdf' },
  { title: '01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,12/14/2018,10.14.03 AM.pdf' },
  { title: '04 Images > Image0010-image44005.jpg' },
  { title: '04 Images > Image0010-image59323.jpg' } ]
```

This is not the sorting I need. How can I sort an array of strings correctly if each string contains a date/time in addition to numerics and letters?

Comment: "This is not the sorting I need". Then explain accurately how would your sorting need to work

Comment: if natural sort is what you need your output is actually correct. maybe it's another type of sorting you need?

Comment: @juvian, Yes, you are right, my question was not clear enough. The sorting is not correct, the second item in the sorting output should come first, because it is AM. So, the solution down there with its correction in the comment solved the issue and the output is correctly ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could normalize date and time to ISO and sort by `localeCompare` with options.

```js
function normalize(s) {
    return s
        .replace(/(\d\d)(\/)(\d\d)(\/)(\d\d\d\d)/g, '$5-$3-$1')
        .replace(/(\d{1,2}\.\d\d\.\d\d)\s([AP]M)/g, (_, t, m) => {
            var p = t.split('.').map(Number);
            if (p[0] === 12) {
                p[0] = 0;
            }
            if (m === 'PM') {
                p[0] += 12;
            }
            return p.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2 , '0')).join(':');
        });
}

let documentData = [{ title:'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,06/14/2018,1.14.03 PM.pdf' }, { title:'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,06/14/2018,5.14.03 AM.pdf' }, { title:'04 Images > Image0010-image59323.jpg' }, { title:'04 Images > Image0010-image44005.jpg' }, { title:'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,08/04/2018,5.14.03 PM.pdf' }, { title:'01 Documents >File0010-Donia5,12/14/2018,10.14.03 AM.pdf' }];
    
documentData.sort((a, b) => normalize(a.title).localeCompare(normalize(b.title), undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }));

console.log(documentData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for the answer, but in the output, I still cannot see the correct order, the August item shows before the June item, can you adjust the code to fix that?

Comment: All you really need to is change "06/14/2018" to "2018/06/14" so `.replace(/(\d\d\/\d\d)\/(\d{4})/,'$2/$1')` since the month and day are already in the "right" order. ;-)